# How to avoid android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, web-services, asynchronous

I am trying to send a picture to my local web server from my android phone. Once it connects to the web server I get the following: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

I think that the solution to my problem is to make the method async. This is something I am not familiar with.

So my question is:
How can I make the following method async?

```
public class Send {
    public Send(){
    }

public static String send(String path) throws Exception {
    String filePath = path;
    String svar;

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("path to web server"); 
        FileBody pic = new FileBody(new File(filePath)); 
        MultipartEntity requestEntity = new MultipartEntity(); 
        requestEntity.addPart("file", pic);

        httppost.setEntity(requestEntity);
        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

        ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(outstream);
        byte [] responseBody = outstream.toByteArray();
        svar = new String(responseBody);
        System.out.println(svar);

    } finally {
        try {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } 
        catch (Exception ignore) {
      }
    }
    return svar;
  }

}
```

Comment: Just tap `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` on Google and you will have a lot of examples using an `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking operations cannot be performed on the main thread, as this would give poor user experience.

An `AsyncTask` is not hard to work out. The `doInBackground` method runs on another thread. The `onPostExecute` method allows you to update the UI, as this method runs on the main thread. Updating the UI is not allowed from any other threads.

Comment: Do I have to wrtie the AsyncTask in an activity or is it fine to put it in a regular class? I get a nullPointerException but I don't see why

Comment: Turns out you probably have to, It worked when I moved the code to an activity,

Comment: An `AsyncTask` can be a regular class: `public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<DoInBackgroundParam, OnProgressUpdateParam, DoInBackgroundReturnValue>`. See [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can not perform any network operation in main Thread. To get rid of problem do the network related tasks in another thread, or `AsyncTask`

For Details check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: Would you mind writing a code snippet that creates a new thread which this is run in? Wouldbe greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Mat check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/931982..

Answer (score 0):

Android system do not allow long operations on the UI Thread so it is free to handle all the interface operations, that include network operations or long data access.

Like others said, the correct method to do those network operations is using an AsyncTask.

This tutorial was a great help for me when i had the same problem =)

http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/116/Android+Threads,+Handlers+and+AsyncTask/